# Disqus privacy icon misaligned in Jekyll blog

Tags: html, css, jekyll, disqus

I'm trying to integrate Disqus into my Jekyll blog however when I view the website on my iPhone6 the Privacy icon is misaligned like so:

[image]

It seems that maybe there isn't enough width for it to align correctly. From what I understand the Disqus icons span the width of the Jekyll blog. Is there a way I can fix this or maybe make the content of the whole blog a little wider? Code at: https://github.com/kekearif/kekearif.github.io

Comment: you could raise an issue for the theme you're using. or you could fix it, and then send a pull request to them, if you can.

Comment: That's just general advice, nothing in particular in how to fix that.